# How to connect React.js forms with the properties of a C# model

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, integration

I'm trying to do a C# and React application, and now I'm in the part where I would integrate both parts, I used some tutorials to help me setup and already did the insert in the controller class for example, that I'm already using ASP.NET Core MVC, for `ControllerBase`, but in the tutorial that I was relying on, the guy used tag helpers in a `.cshtml` file to make the form, while I wanted to use React.js, so I could handle the front end with, and only rely on C# to make the CRUD operations.

I wanted to integrate this:

`lembreteModel.cs`:

```
namespace PersonalReminders.Models
{
    public class LembreteModel
    {   
        public string? Descricao { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data {get; set; }
    }
}
```

With this form in react.js:

```
    return (
      <div className='telaInicial'>
        <h4>Novo lembrete</h4>
        <form>
          Lembrete:
          <input type='text' name='descricao' placeholder='digite o lembrete'></input>
          Data:
          <input type='date' name='data' placeholder='digite a data do lembrete. '></input>
          <button>Criar lembrete</button>
        </form>
        <h4>lista de Lembretes</h4>        
      </div>
    );
```

Any ideas of how to proceed?

Comment: Show us the code where you make the request to the server from the browser.

Comment: thats what im i need, a way to connect, transfer the data typed in the form from the browser to my database table, if your meant another thing and i got it wrong, just to clarify that i used the code base of react,js and c# provided by Visual Studio, so for example to make the connection via localhost, i just needed to include "/lembrete" in the SetupProxy.js, besides that i coded the Model, that is above, Controller( with the CRUD), Sqlite Database(to make CRUD possible), and TelaInicial.js (my React file), besides that everything came ready.